# The number of foldable regions is limited to a maximum of 5000. Increase configuration option 'Folding Maximum Regions' to enable more

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am facing this issue while installing npm in vs code[image]

I have deleted node modules folder and installing again

Comment: you don't install `npm` in VSCode. You install NodeJS in the OS and you get `npm` for free. Then you can use `node` and `npm` in the terminal (of VSCode). What are the exact steps you take?

Comment: Can someone explain what is a "foldable region" ?

Answer (score 12):

This happen if you open a large file (I got this notification when I opened a file with 60000 lines).
Consider increasing this value to avoid this notification

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you use the internal terminal of VS Code to install npm modules. You can just close and reopen the VS code after installing the modules and the error won't come again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the number of lines in the editor.foldingMaximumRegions.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the terminal and start a new one to get rid of the error. Also, you have to start your environment with  (`npm start`) or (`yarn start`) in new terminal.